# Stop all Javascript execution (client-side) based on a specific resolution of any promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, terminate

I am looping through a bunch of API calls and I would like to stop if I receive a 429 (too many requests) status code.

I can't figure out a way to actually do this. I wanted to just break the loop, but I get an "Illegal break operation" compilation error

```
for (let i = 0; i < 150000; i++) {
callAPI(i).then((data)=>{
            if(data.status === 404){addData("APICalls", {GroupDeleted:i})};
            if(data.status === 200){addData("APICalls", data);};
            if(data.status === 429){console.log("Too Many Requests: " + i); <Stop execution>;};     
            });
}

async function callAPI(ID) {
    let data = await fetch(`...my fetch...`
    return await data.json();
}
```

Comment: Because the stop execution is inside the callback, it will run only when any data is received. Due to the nature of Asynchronous functions, it could be possible that the loop could have ended by the time a response has been received.

Answer (score 0):

I have outlined a possible solution below, But I'm afraid this will delay the execution significantly as the program waits for responses for each request.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 150000; i++) {
   let data = await callApi(i);
   // Do stuff with data
   if( data.status === 429 ) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let stop = false;

for (let i = 0; i < 150000; i++) {
if(stop){
  break;
}
callAPI(i).then((data)=>{
            if(data.status === 404){addData("APICalls", {GroupDeleted:i})};
            if(data.status === 200){addData("APICalls", data);};
            if(data.status === 429){console.log("Too Many Requests: " + i) **stop=true**; <Stop execution>;};     
            });
}

async function callAPI(ID) {
    let data = await fetch(`...my fetch...`
    return await data.json();

}`enter code here`
```

Could you give this code a try?